# asp.NET IIS and scripting

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I have recently installed IIS on my Windows Xp Proffesional machine, created a .asp file with this syntax:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <% Response.write("Hello World") %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And my output when i run it looks like this:
    `<% Response.write("Hello World") %>`

Does this mean my IIS was not installed correctly? Cause I am pretty sure this should only be printing  "Hello World" (but without quotes)

And for clarity I am the administrator for my machine so there is no issue with me not being the admin.

Comment: you should take a look if the solution is running in visual studio local server or in IIS.

Comment: i saved the file in a newly created folder according to the asp tutorials on w3schools.com and have had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have all ready install dot net on your computer, you then open your Internet Information Services window (from control panel open the Administrative Tools, there is the IIS) , select your site (by default is only one), right click on it, go the the tab "Home Directory" and on Application Settings, make it Application.

After that your page must be run.

Comment: this did not work for me. Maybe something went wrong with my installation not exactly sure. i keep getting this error when i run the default page: Unexpected error 0x8ffe2740 occurred

Comment: @androidAm1984 check this out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816944  say that you have some port conflict.